# Swift protocol with generic method: invalid redeclaration of implementation

Tags: swift, generics

I'm playing with some protocol/generic stuff in Swift and I'm curious why following code is refusing to be compiled:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func value<T>() -> T
}

class StringImpl: MyProtocol {
    var string: String

    init() {
        self.string = "..."
    }

    init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }

    func value<String>() -> String {
        return self.string as! String
    }
}

class BoolImpl: MyProtocol {
    var value: Bool

    init() {
        self.value = false
    }

    init(value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func value<Bool>() -> Bool {
        return self.value as! Bool
    }
}
```

with particular error

```
error: invalid redeclaration of 'value()'
func value<Bool>() -> Bool {
```

It may imply that I cannot have different implementations of protocol generic method, but I don't see clear reason why.

(I'm not speaking of force type cast as generic type shadows existing one)

P.S. For those who are curious I may tell that I'm trying to make protocol that is not messed with associatedtype and still is generic to some degree.

Comment: @matt, I guess so, as without it compiler will fail because of "does not conform to protocol" error

Comment: So ask yourself why you have to say `as! String`. You are not resolving a generic, you are just using String as a generic. Everyone seems to be missing the real problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no problem the mistake is `var value`, and redeclaring a function with name of `func value<Bool>`, i just changed the variable name and it worked, the error clearly says

> error: invalid redeclaration of 'value()'

```
class BoolImpl: MyProtocol {
var bool: Bool

init() {
    self.bool = false
}

init(value: Bool) {
    self.bool = value
}

func value<Bool>() -> Bool {
    return self.bool as! Bool
}
}
```

Comment: Wow. My bad! Definitely, compiler doesn't allow us to do such thing, but I was not very attentive this noon. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: @BohdanIvanov it's ok glad to help

Answer (score 2):

> error: invalid redeclaration of 'value()'

The thing is that. Your method has same name as your variable and it also **returns the same type**. So, compiler tells you that this isn't legal.

---

Anyway, you should think if you really need this method. You can add this `value` property to protocol and it also looks like you need `associatedtype` for your protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var value: T { get set }
}

class StringImpl: MyProtocol {
    typealias T = String
    var value: T = "..."

    init(string: T) {
        value = string
    }
}

class BoolImpl: MyProtocol {
    typealias T = Bool
    var value: T = false

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

then, if you need just value of your object, you can just get `value` property

```
someStringImpl.value
someBoolImpl.value
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to add associatedtype. It would be too constrained in case I will need, for example, to create collection of MyProtocol's

Comment: It seems you can remove 'getValue()' method :)

Comment: @Vyacheslav yes, I mentioned this in my answer. I just wanted to keep it for showing logic.

Comment: @RobertDresler, true, but still with this approach I can have [MyProtocol] created with any additional changes. But yes, it is impossible to create something generic without proper generic.

Comment: The funny thing is that removing `func value<Bool>() -> Bool` will result in `does not conform to protocol` error, so in that case compiler will not look at `var value: Bool` as at protocol conformance.

Comment: @BohdanIvanov yes, because `value` as method isn't `value` as variable. Anyway, read updated first paragraph of my answer. Error occurs because it has same name and it returns the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 'value' variable name is the same as 'value' function name

```
class BoolImpl: MyProtocol {
    var storedValue: Bool

    init() {
        self.storedValue = false
    }

    init(value: Bool) {
        self.storedValue = value
    }

    func value<Bool>() -> Bool {
        return self.storedValue as! Bool
    }
}
```

Comment: what does that add to my answer ?

Comment: @MohmmadS I didn't see your answer. It might they were posted nearly at the same time.

Comment: oh, its fine :D

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be missing the point here.

You seem to think that your adopters of

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func value<T>() -> T
}
```

...resolve the generic. They do not. They merely *repeat* the generic.

For example, think about your

```
func value<String>() -> String {
    return self.string as! String
}
```

`self.string` is a string. So ask yourself why you have to say `as! String`. It’s because you are misusing String as a placeholder name just like T. You would get the same result using a nonsense word:

```
func value<Stringgg>() -> Stringgg {
    return self.string as! Stringgg
}
```

That compiles too. You still haven’t resolved the generic, you merely changed its name. Your attempt to avoid an associated type has failed. Your code compiles but it can never run.

Comment: Oh, now I understand it. So actually Bool in `func value<Bool>() -> Bool` is not boolean but rather generic type and that is why I'm having errors (and why types are shadowed by each other). Thank you! 

So is there any usage for such approach? It feels like I don't need to use generic protocol method as I can already have it in generic class

Comment: I have no idea what your long term goal is. I’m just saying that if you want to avoid a generic protocol this is not how to do it.